# Quiz plugin where we can import question from Excel file?

Tags: plugins

Is there any Quiz plugin for WP where is possible to import question from Excel file. I try WP Pro quiz, but it can just import xml files.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin [MT-Quiz-Import](https://www.fiverr.com/fastjobber/setup-google-spreadsheet-or-excel-for-quiz-publishing-on-wordpress-or-a-website) allowes you to import excel files to WP Pro Quiz, but its not free.